# Identify multiple href redirection to a file

Tags: php, html

I have multiple links redirecting to a file `list.php`. We wish to identify through which link redirection to the file `list.php` was done  . I tried to use `variables`  but it didnt work as by issuing `GET` in `list.php` the variables `var2 ,var3 ,var4 ,var5`  in the file `list.php` were  having the respective values defined in `href` file.

```
<a href="list.php" var2=<?php echo "$var2" ?>> A </a></div>
<a href="list.php" var3=<?php echo "$var3" ?>> B </a></div>
<a href="list.php" var4=<?php echo "$var4" ?>> C </a></div>
<a href="list.php" var5=<?php echo "$var5" ?>> D  </a></div>

<?php   
$var2 = $GET['var2'];
$var3 = $GET['var3'];
$var4 = $GET['var4'];
$var5 = $GET['var5'];
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<a href="list.php?var2=<?php echo "$var2" ?>">A</a>`? (And similar for the others...)

Comment: it is not $GET, it should be $_GET if you are trying to fetch the value send via HTTP GET method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your HTML document, you can do this:

```
<a href="list.php?var2=<?php echo "$var2"; ?>">A</a>
<a href="list.php?var3=<?php echo "$var3"; ?>">B</a>
<a href="list.php?var4=<?php echo "$var4"; ?>">C</a>
<a href="list.php?var5=<?php echo "$var5"; ?>">D</a>
```

and inside your PHP script, you can do this:

```
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
$var3 = $_GET['var3'];
$var4 = $_GET['var4'];
$var5 = $_GET['var5'];
```